# Proving that $\sum \limits_{d^2|n}\ \mu (d)=\mu^2(n)$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\mu$ be the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function). Then prove that $\sum \limits_{d^2|n}\ \mu (d)=\mu^2(n)$, and more generally
$$
\sum \limits_{d^k|n}\ \mu (d) =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if } m^k \mid n \\
1 &\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mu$ is multiplicative, you need only show this for prime powers. So you want to show the pair
$$ \sum_{d^2 \mid p} \mu(d) = 1,$$
which is trivial, and
$$ \sum_{d^2 \mid p^k} \mu(d) = 0$$
for $k \geq 2$, which is easy once you realize how easy it is to describe the square factors of prime powers. This methodology holds similarly for more general powers instead of squares.

Comment: Can you be more explicit please?? @mixedmath

Comment: You've left out the part about showing that $\sum_{d^2\mid n} f(d)$ is multiplicative whenever $f$ is. This is well-known for $\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)$, less so for this case.

Comment: @mixedmath Do we proceed in the same way for $d^k|n$ ? And are the result as stated above I mean 1 or 0? not $\mu ^k(n)$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using Dirichlet series. Observe that
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{ks}} = \frac{1}{\zeta(ks)}.$$

Therefore
$$L(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{\sum_{d^k|n}\mu(d)}{n^{s}} = 
\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(ks)}.$$

This has Euler product
$$L(s) = \prod_p \frac{1-1/p^{ks}}{1-1/p^s}.$$

Note that this is
$$\prod_p \left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}+\frac{1}{p^{2s}}+\cdots
+ \frac{1}{p^{(k-1)s}}\right).$$

It now follows by inspection that
$$L(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1} 
\frac{[[\not\exists m^k|n]]}{n^s}.$$