# Prove $\sum\limits_{d^2 \mid n} \mu(d) = \mu^2(n)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am not satisfied with the proof found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258239/proving-that-sum-limits-d2n-mu-d-mu2n-where-mu-is-the-m%C3%B6bius)

Let $f(n) = \sum\limits_{d^2 \mid n} \mu(d)$

Stating without proof, $f(n)$ is multiplicative.

Now for $n = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^k p_i^{a_i}$

$f(n) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^k f(p_i^{a_i}) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^k \sum\limits_{d^2 \mid p_i^{a_i}} \mu(d)$

If $n$ has a square factor, then for every square factor, we would get terms of the form $\mu(1) + \mu(p) = 0$.

If $n$ is square free, then $f(n) = \mu(1) = 1$

I can see the answer being $\mu(n)$ but fail to see why the answer should be $\mu^2(n)$

Thanks

Comment: The key result is that $f(n)=1$ if $n$ is square free.  Let $n=p$ be a prime.  That's square free, but $\mu(p)=-1$, not $1$.

Comment: Let $b(n) = \mu(\sqrt{n})$ (so that $b(n) = 0$ if $n$ is not a square). It is multiplicative so that $f(n) = \sum_{d | n} b(d)$ is multiplicative and it is enough to look at $f(p^k)$. Also $\sum_n b(n) n^{-s} = \sum_n \mu(n) n^{-2s} = \frac{1}{\zeta(2s)}$ thus $\sum_n \sum_{d | n} b(d) n^{-s} = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)} = \prod_p (1+p^{-s}) = \sum_n \mu(n)^2 n^{-s}$

Comment: @user1952009, could you give me a simple example where the answer $\mu^2(n)$ becomes evident. For example, if $n = p_1, f(n) = 1$. If $n = p_1^2, f(n) = 0$, if $n = p_1p_2, f(n) = 1$ and so on.

Comment: $f(p^k) = 1_{k \le 1}$ means that $f(n) =\prod_{p^k \| n} f(p^k)= 1_{n \text{ is squarefree}} = \mu(n)^2$

Comment: More generally : $f(n)$ and $\mu(n)^2$ are multiplicative and $f(p^k) = \mu(p^k)^2$ for every $p^k$ thus $f(n) = \mu(n)^2$ for every $n$

Comment: Oh,,,, since the answer is always either 1 or 0, we are using $\mu^2(n)$. I think I get it. I thought there was some other magic..

Comment: Thank you @user1952009

Comment: I feel quite stupid :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have for a multiplicative function $f(n)$ that

$$\sum_{d^2|n} f(d^2) =
\prod_{p|n} (1 + f(p^2) + f(p^4) + \cdots + f(p^{2w}))$$

where $p^v$ are the primes that  divide $n$, $v$ is the corresponding
power and $w=\lfloor v/2\rfloor$. Now group the primes so that $p$
has exponent $v=1$ and $q$ has $v\gt 1$ to get

$$\prod_{p|n} 1
\prod_{q|n} (1 + f(q^2) + f(q^4) + \cdots + f(q^{2w})).$$

This yields with $f(n) = \mu(\sqrt{n})$ where $f(n)=0$ if $n$ is not a square as suggested by @reuns for

$$\sum_{d^2|n} \mu(\sqrt{d^2})$$ the product

$$\prod_{p|n} 1
\prod_{q|n} (1 - 1 + 0 + 0 + \cdots).$$

It follows that the value is zero when $n$ is not squarefree and
one otherwise which is

$$\mu(n)^2$$

as claimed.