# Möbius function multiplicativity

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I have to prove that $$\mu(n)^2=\sum_{d^2\mid n}\mu (d).$$

The hint is that I have to show that both sides are multiplicative.

However I don't see why if $n,m$ are coprime, then $$\left(\sum_{d^2\mid n}\mu(d)\right)\left( \sum_{d^2\mid m}\mu(d)\right)=\sum_{d^2\mid nm} 
\mu(d)\,?$$

Comment: If $d^2 \mid mn$, and $(m, n) = 1$, then we can write $d^2 = e^2f^2$, where $e^2 \mid m$ and $f^2 \mid n$. What can you say about $\mu(e)\mu(f)$?

Comment: $\mu(e)\mu(f)=\mu(ef)=\mu(d)$ ? Are $e$ and $f$ coprime ?

Comment: Right, because $e \mid e^2 \mid m$, and $f \mid f^2 \mid n$, so if $g = (e, f)$, then $g \mid m, n \implies g = 1$.

Comment: See also: [Proving that $\sum \limits_{d^2|n}\ \mu (d)=\mu^2(n)$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1258239)
and [Prove $\sum\limits_{d^2 \mid n} \mu(d) = \mu^2(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2326698). And this question is specifically related to the part about the multiplicativity: [Sum over square divisors is multiplicative proof verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1837522).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof of the desired result (not using the hint though):

Write $n = \prod p_i^{e_i}$ for positive $e_i$ so that
$$\sum_{d^2\mid n} \mu(d) = \sum_{d \mid m} \mu(d) = \begin{cases}1 & m=1 \\ 0 & m>1,\end{cases}$$
where $m = \prod p_i^{\lfloor{e_i/2}\rfloor}.$

$m=1$ precisely when $\left\lfloor\frac{e_i}2 \right\rfloor = 0 \implies e_i = 1 \text{ for each }i \implies n$ squarefree.

$\mu(n)^2 = |\mu(n)|$ follows exactly the same definition.

Comment: Thank you :) Great answer